# How to export databases with commands azure cli on python script

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, python-3.7, azure-cli

I use **Azure CLI** to export backup the databases in my resource group to the **blobstorage**, so i want to use same command on **python script**.

For example, I use the following command in Azure CLI to export the DB's in my resource group:

```
az sql db export -s (sql server) -n (database) -g (group) -p (password)
  -u login --storage-key " key "
  --storage-key-type
  --storage-uri (url blob)
```

How can I achieve this using a Python script instead?

Answer (score 1):

To build up on the previous answers with an up to date version of the sdk you may follow those steps :

- Go to microsoft entra (previously active directory) and register a new app: [https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/~/RegisteredApps](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/%7E/RegisteredApps)
- Open your newly created app and create a new Client secret from the "Certificates & secrets" section (be sure to copy the password as it won't be shown anymore)
- Open you SQL server and un der "Access Control (IAM)" section add the role "SQL DB Contributor" to your app

Then you can

```
pip install azure-mgmt-sql
pip install azure-mgmt-compute
```

And in python

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.sql import SqlManagementClient

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
    client_id='<the id of your app>',
    client_secret='<the secret of your app>',
    tenant_id='<the id of the entra tenant>'
)

sql_client = SqlManagementClient(credentials, '<the id of your subscription>')

poller = sql_client.databases.begin_export(
    database_name='<your database name>',
    server_name='<your database server name (without .database.windows.net)>',
    resource_group_name='<your database server resource group>',
    parameters={
        'storage_key_type': 'StorageAccessKey',
        'storage_key': '<your storage key>',
        'storage_uri': 'https://<your storage account>.blob.core.windows.net/<your blob container>/<name of output file>.bacpac',
        'administrator_login': '<database user>',
        'administrator_login_password': '<database password>',
        'authentication_type': 'SQL'
    }
)

print(poller.result())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API from Python to export an Azure SQL Database as a bacpac.

This is a sample request.

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/sqlcrudtest-4799/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqlcrudtest-5961/databases/testdb/export?api-version=2014-04-01
```

Request body.

```
{
  "storageKeyType": "SharedAccessKey",
  "storageKey": "?sr=b&sp=rw&se=2018-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&sig=sdfsdfklsdjflSLIFJLSIEJFLKSDJFDd/%2wdfskdjf3%3D&sv=2015-07-08",
  "storageUri": "https://test.blob.core.windows.net/bacpacs/testbacpac.bacpac",
  "administratorLogin": "dummyLogin",
  "administratorLoginPassword": "Un53cuRE!",
  "authenticationType": "SQL"
}
```

Sample response.

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/sqlcrudtest-4799/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqlcrudtest-5961/importExportOperationResult/f01d7bfe-7162-44e7-9350-f1c85ce83e4c",
  "name": "f01d7bfe-7162-44e7-9350-f1c85ce83e4c",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/importExportOperationResults",
  "properties": {
    "requestId": "f01d7bfe-7162-44e7-9350-f1c85ce83e4c",
    "requestType": "Export",
    "queuedTime": "3/1/2017 12:14:25 AM",
    "lastModifiedTime": "3/1/2017 12:16:33 AM",
    "blobUri": "https://test.blob.core.windows.net/bacpacs/test.bacpac",
    "serverName": "test",
    "databaseName": "testdb",
    "status": "Completed",
    "errorMessage": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to install the **azure-mgmt-sql==0.16.0** package using pip.

Adjust parameters in the following code snippet and you should be good to go.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.sql import SqlManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.sql.models import StorageKeyType, AuthenticationType
from msrestazure.azure_exceptions import CloudError


TENANT_ID = '<your_tennant_id>'
CLIENT = '<your_client_id>'
KEY = '<your_client_key>'
SUBSCRIPTION_ID = '<your_subscription_id>'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id=CLIENT,
    secret=KEY,
    tenant=TENANT_ID
)

sql_client = SqlManagementClient(credentials, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)

kwargs = dict()
kwargs['storage_key_type'] = 'StorageAccessKey'
kwargs['storage_key'] = '<your_storage_account_key'
kwargs['storage_uri'] = 'https://<name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/<name>.bacpac'
kwargs['administrator_login'] = '<admin_name>'
kwargs['administrator_login_password'] = '<admin_password>'
kwargs['authentication_type'] = 'SQL'

try:
    poller = sql_client.databases.export(
        database_name='<your_db_name>',
        server_name='<your_server_name>',
        resource_group_name='<your_rg_name>',
        storage_key_type='StorageAccessKey',
        storage_key='<your_storage_account_key',
        parameters=kwargs)

    print(poller.result())

except CloudError as err:
    print(err.error)
    print(err.message)
```